# How to create a class only for string manipulation and usable in all other classes for specific manipulations that repeats in other classes

Tags: php

I have a class:

```
class Users { ... }
```

Which I want in some methods to manipulate the string to be lowecase/uppercase/camelized/etc, and not have to re-write the method that does that in all other classes I have.

So i want to create a "strings" class (or interface? or static class?) and re-use the functionality in other classes like `class Apps { ... }` that will be used for only calculations or strings manipulations.

I once new how to do it but just cant remember.

Comment: You might want to look into traits - http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php

Comment: I see basically two choices: make a class for strings (like `ArrayObject` for arrays) or use a trait.

Comment: PHP already have function for all those manipulations. What would be the point of wrapping them? P.S. use of traits is an extremely bad practice.

Comment: @tereško Ok, so lets say I want to calculate an average (in mor than one class) and I divide by 0 and want to throw a specific exception? or any other manipulations (might be on arrays too) that happen too commonly all over my classes? I just want to write some functions for that kind of stuff too

Comment: You example is too abstract. And if you have the same manipulation happening all over your codebase, then your domain structure is probably malformed. The same type of manipulation usually would happen only to same type of actors in your domain structure and in such case the simplest approach is to create Value Object, that contains all this repeated logic.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for Traits (http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php)

```
<?php

trait StringUtils
{
    protected function toLower($value)
    {
        return mb_strtolower($value);
    }

    protected function toUpper($value)
    {
        return mb_strtoupper($value);
    }
}

class User
{
    use StringUtils;

    private $name;

    public function __construct($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
    }

    public function displayName()
    {
        return $this->toLower($this->name);
    }
}

$me = new User('Rick');

echo $me->displayName(); // rick
```

Comment: This is a harmful practice.

Comment: @tereško because of the namespace thing?

Comment: Because traits are actually a compiler level copy-paste. And a use of it usually indicated a *code smell*, because your domain structure is all messed up.

Comment: @tereško OP asked for a way to reuse functionality in classes that they can't remember, and my answer replies to that question, and Traits are exactly meant for that. Traits are not harmful in general, copy&paste is not harmful in general, only generalizations are :)

Comment: @jeromegamez Your answer works. Harmful practice is blanket over generalizations making code needlessly complex. Its much like when someone says you must use prepared statements for every single query you do (even a query only having logic-built integer variables in it).

Comment: @jeromegamez traits are **harmful in general**. There is no way around it. Same way as eval is harmful in general. Both are harmful practices, with niche usecase. You were probably trying to be funny, but what you actually said was just stupid.